# Android: Handle key press on virtual keyboard in WebView

Tags: android, keyboard, webview, virtual

I need a hint in such problem.
I'm using WebView on android 2.2

How can I handle key pressing on virtual keyboard in WebView. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery keypress() can be used for this.

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/